# How to listen to global events when using requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Assume I have the following in my script.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  alert("DOM loaded!");
});
```

And I enclose the above inside define function of requirejs.

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
], function($, _, Backbone) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    alert("DOM loaded!"); // I AM NEVER CALLED :(
  });
});
```

It seems the DOM content has already loaded by the time requireJS has loaded the defined modules inside the script. The same problem persists when I have to listen to other global events like `youtubeIframeAPIReady`. What's the convention to solve such problem when using requireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to deal with `DOMContentLoaded` is to use jQuery's [`$.ready`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) if you are using jQuery or use RequireJS' [`domReady`](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) plugin if you are not. (Well, you can use `domReady` even if you are using jQuery but I don't see much point to it.) Both jQuery and `domReady` are able to handle the case where `DOMContentLoaded` happens before these methods are used.

With jQuery your code would become:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
], function($, _, Backbone) {
  $(function() {
    alert("DOM loaded!");
  });
});
```

The code above calls `$` with a function which is an abbreviated way of using `$.ready`. With `domReady` you could do:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'domReady!',
], function($, _, Backbone) {
    alert("DOM loaded!");
});
```

Used this way, the code in the callback to `define` won't execute until the DOM has loaded.

I do not know of an equivalent for `youtubeIframeAPIReady`.